# Rest api - adding tags to an entity

Tags: api, rest, tagging, api-design

I am designing a rest api in which I need to add tags to an entity. The entity is created using `POST /content` where the json data is passed in the request body. I want to allow adding tags while the `POST` request is being made, and also later on. This is what I have.

```
POST /content?tag=foo&tag=bar

PUT  /content/{id}?tag=baz&tag=bat
```

Now, how do I allow deleting tags? What would be a better approach>

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: is you would do it like this

Assuming your entity is the content in your to create an entity you would:

```
POST /entity
```

This will create an entity and return an entity id, for example 29292

if you need to add tags on an entity you would go down the hierarchy like this:

```
POST /entity/29292/tags
```

to delete tags you would simply

```
DELETE /entity/29292/tags
```

Long answer: you want to study [this guideline](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) on creating restful apis that has a lot more details and best practices.