# REST API-What is a Tag?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, tagging

I'm trying to integrate with a 3rd party REST API, and in their specification, they have mentioned about adding 'Tags' to an entity (Due to NDA I'm unable to disclose the exact requirement/documentation). During my research, it appeared  that 'Tags' is a common terminology related to REST API.
(Following Stack over flow question is also related to adding a tag.
[Rest api - adding tags to an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822383/rest-api-adding-tags-to-an-entity))

However, I could not find proper documentation or answer that explains what is a 'Tag' and what purpose it serves, so I am confused about it. Therefore, I have following questions.

1. Is Tag/tagging is a common terminology in REST APIs?
2. If above is Yes,What is a 'Tag' in REST API, and what is the purpose of having Tags?  (If there are any good sample implementation/documentation which explains the tagging in ASP.NET please share)

Comment: Tagging is usually done to group data. For example, you tagged this question with `rest`, `asp.net-web-api2` and `tagging` to bring it to the attention of people monitoring their areas of expertise.

Comment: Yes, generally Tagging is what you explained. But what I am trying to understand is what it means in REST API. Can you please explain more in the REST API context, may be with a technical/code example.

Comment: It has nothing to do with REST API. Even the link you provided in your question is about data. An "entity" is the data side. Reread your requirements and see if it is asking to add an endpoint that allows the tagging of data.